# Worst case of heuristics for symmetric TSP

Tags: tsp, greedy-algorithms

I have implemented the nearest neighbor heuristic for solving symmetric TSP problems.
I was wondering if there is any relation between the solution found by the heuristic and the optimal solution?

Can we state theoretically how much higher the route length is in a worst case scenario?

Same question for simulated annealing, tabu-search and 2-opt search.

Comment: Related: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18307/approximation-for-metric-tsp-worst-case-using-nearest-neighbor-heuristic, see also: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19822/heuristics-for-tsp-without-triangle-inequality

Comment: I'm sorry, but 'quite well' is not really a theoretical upper bound...

Comment: Potentially related as well: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/a-simple-approximation-algorithm-for-the-tsp

Comment: For 2-opt check [Chandra, Karloff, and Tovey 1999]. Lower bound is Omega(log(n)/loglog(n)).

Comment: It can be far from optimal by logarithmic factor. This stated in a first linked question.